# WP ALL IMPORT - Variation

Tags: wordpress, wpallimport

I'm trying to import products from a link, the link can't be shared but I'm going to share some content so you can help me.

My problem is with variations, so I'm trying to import some shoes and clothes, each product has some variations like size and color, each variation has quantity, in the XML file each variant is called attribute-1, attribute-2 ... etc .. as shown in the pic below.
[an image showing the attributes from the XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFfY6.png)

as you see I have many attributes but because of the naming used in the file (Attribute-**1**)
As shown in the below pic, the tool recognizes only 1 attribute, so how can I make it recognize all the attributes in the file?

[an image showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGZNi.png)

My second question is how can I add quantity to every variation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the XML as a code snippet here?

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. I managed to solve the problem by using this expression

{attributes[1]/child::*}

Comment: Great - feel free to answer your own question and mark it as the accepted answer - for anyone who can have this issue in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by selecting all the child elements
It can be easily done by using this expression: child::*

for my example this worked:  `{attributes[1]/child::*}`